# Kotlin Nested Coroutine Launches not triggering?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've noticed sometimes when I have a Kotlin Coroutine'launch' nested within another 'launch' that it doesn't always fire.

For instance, I've got this code:

```
private suspend fun askToAddFriend() {
        val friendExists = friendExists(userUsername)

        if (!friendExists) {

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                AlertDialog.Builder(this@EntryActivity)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.send_friend_request))
                        .setMessage("${getString(R.string.would_you_like_to_add)} $userDisplayName ${getString(R.string.as_a_friend_questionmark)}")
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes)) { dialog, which ->
                            dialog.dismiss()

                            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                SendRequestHelper(this@EntryActivity).requestFriend(userUsername, userFirestoreDocumentId)
                            }

                            AlertDialog.Builder(this@EntryActivity)
                                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.friend_request_sent))
                                    .setMessage("${getString(R.string.weve_sent_friend_request_to)} $userDisplayName")
                                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog2, _ ->
                                        dialog2.dismiss()
                                    }
                                    .setOnDismissListener { callback.invoke() }
                                    .create().show()
                        }
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no)) { dialog, which ->
                            dialog.dismiss()
                            callback.invoke()
                        }
                        .create().show()
            }

        }
}
```

Now I've been debugging, and I placed a breakpoint in the `requestFriend` method of the `SendRequestHelper` class. And the breakpoint never hits.
Even though it's gone past that code, because my second `AlertDialog` has shown up fine.

What's going on here?

Should I not be nesting `launch` statements? What stops it working?

Thanks

Comment: ensure that your nested launch has main launch's scope.

Comment: Instead of launching `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` to show the dialog..you could directly showed the dialog.. ( **there was no need for nesting in this case** ) also check if the debug breaks are showing **tick marks** .. else you can add log and test

Comment: @SantanuSur if I don't use the `Dispatchers.Main` context the Android framework will say I'm not on the main thread to be creating views?

Comment: @user8159708 it seems u are already in the `main thread` ..can you provide the `launch` function for `askToAddFriend()`

Answer (score 0):

That's what you have right now (not working code)

```
dialog.dismiss()
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
     SendRequestHelper(this@EntryActivity).requestFriend(userUsername, userFirestoreDocumentId)
}
```

As this code runs on Positive Button Click then you have to define what actually is the scope of the action. `launch` function simple fires and forgets so in Button Click function you don't simple have the scope cached (that's my assumption)

```
dialog.dismiss()
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
     SendRequestHelper(this@EntryActivity).requestFriend(userUsername, userFirestoreDocumentId)
}
```

More abour that you can find [here](https://medium.com/@elizarov/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055)

Please also notice, that `GlobalScope` is not for that case, as it keeps active over whole appliaction lifecycle.
You should probably have another scope like ViewModel scope to run your job in that one.

More is [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471)